# How to subset a netCDF data (rotated grid) using lat-lon in R programming?

Tags: r, subset, netcdf

I want to subset and convert the rotated grid rlat-rlon to regular grid data.
I have used "cmsaf" pacckage but it gives following error-

```
box_mergetime("tas", wd, "tas_WAS-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp45_r12i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v2_day_20060101-20101231", "example", 69, 78.5, 22.5, 30)
```

get file information

```
[1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in 
  the file!" 

[1] "var (or dimvar) name: longitude"

[1] "file name: C:/Users/Deepak/Documents/eg/tas_WAS-44_ICHEC-EC EARTH_rcp45_r12i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v2_day_20060101-20101231.nc"

Error in vobjtovarid4(nc, varid, verbose = verbose, allowdimvar = TRUE) : 
  Variable not found
```

here is the link for sample data file-
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7kCnwkpTGrMRDRTaWpLNlNKMzQ

Comment: You need to change the permissions on the file so people can access it without needed to request.

Comment: hello sir, I have changed the permissions on the file.